# Can I be part of the audience in The Daily Show as a tourist?

Tags: sightseeing, new-york-city

The Daily Show with John Stewart is filmed in New York City. How can someone be in the audience of the show?

Comment: I opened a meta question on this: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/are-questions-about-shows-in-popular-tourist-destinations-on-topic

Comment: I was in the audience for an episode of the David Letterman show. We got offered tickets whilst wandering around the Times Square area; we thought they were trying to rope us into comedy clubs initially, as most of the ticket sellers there are. Apologies, I'm not sure if you're female or not from your name, but it helps if you are or if you're in the company of one or two I think. I believe there are probably some more surefire ways to secure tickets though.

Comment: @Sam, as you can see from my picture, I'm a rhinoceros.

Comment: I've been in the audience for TV shows at least twice when visiting LA as a tourist. Because this is one of the things tourists to LA do. Hence I believe this question is absolutely on topic here! It may also be on topic on the TV Stack Exchange. It is about *both* travel *and* TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be answered in absolute terms since the availability of tickets is not always given. Currently, for example, [nobody can get tickets](http://www.thedailyshow.com/tickets). There is, to my knowledge, no limitations who can get tickets to these shows, as long as they are available at all.

As Ilya noted, [this page described](http://diehardthree.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/how-i-got-standby-tickets-for-the-daily-show/) in late 2012 how you can get standby-tickets by waiting outside of the studio.

Comment: I have signed on the site more than a month ago, and didn't get any answer. Is there maybe some other way to get in?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed I have tried to get a ticket in August already and it was at the same level. I am assuming that they sold out all tickets to an agent or re-distributor, so it seems you won't get tickets from them directly.

Comment: According to [this](http://diehardthree.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/how-i-got-standby-tickets-for-the-daily-show/) you can also get standby tickets without reservation. Please add this info and I'll accept the answer.